# UrlMappings parseRequest:true causes JSON Exception when nothing to parse

Tags: json, grails, groovy

UPDATE: Just found [this bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7445) that looks like my issue.

I'm playing around with a client side framework that works on pure JSON.  I have a UrlMapping as:

```
"/books/$id?"(controller:'book', parseRequest:true) {
    action = [GET:'show',PUT:'update', POST:'save']
}
```

The problem is with the 'show' action in that if there is no id passed into the request, I simply return a JSON list of all the books:

```
def show = {
    if (params.id) {
      def bookInstance = Book.get(params.id)
      render bookInstance as JSON
    }else{
      render Book.list() as JSON
    }
}
```

However, since there is no JSON to parse I'm getting the following exception:

```
2011-06-07 09:45:20,373 [http-8080-1] ERROR converters.JSONParsingParameterCreationListener  - Error parsing incoming JSON request: Error parsing JSON
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error parsing JSON
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:289)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:311)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:334)
    at grails.converters.JSON$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.JSONParsingParameterCreationListener.paramsCreated(JSONParsingParameterCreationListener.groovy:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.informParameterCreationListeners(GrailsWebRequest.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 0 of 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:473)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:358)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:280)
    ... 44 more
```

Is this a bug or is there someway to tell Grails that if no JSON exists, just don't try and parse anything?

Answer (score 1):

> However, since there is no JSON to parse I'm getting the following exception:

I'm not sure why there's no JSON to parse. If `Book.list()` returns an empty List when there are no books, this should be converted to an empty (JavaScript) array. You can verify this by running the following code in the Grails console

```
import grails.converters.*

String json = [] as JSON
assert json == '[]'
```

If `Book.list()` returns null, then you can easily replace it with an empty list by changing

```
render Book.list() as JSON
```

to

```
// If you like micro-optimizations, replace [] with Collections.emptyList()
def allBooks = Book.list() ?: []
render allBooks as JSON
```

Comment: It's not the response, it's that (I think) Grail is looking at the request for something that isn't there.  And it doesn't keep the controller from responding.  It throws up deeper down in the process.

Comment: I edited my question and added a link to a bug in Grails' JIRA that looks like my issue.